# Php PDO extend class using it in other classes without extending class

Tags: php, class, pdo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP and PDO class question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297835/php-and-pdo-class-question)

I was wondering if anyone could help I have a basic php PDO extend class and i wanted to use a global $db in other class to do all the mysql stuff. I can connect to database and that but just want to use a global variable which i can access in any class.

But I dont want to extend the database class with my new classes, i also don't want to pass the database connection var in the class constructor.

is there a way to do this?

here's some coding sample what i want to achive excuse any coding errors..

```
//--DATABASE CLASS
class Database Extends PDO {

    protected $database_hostname = DB_HOST;
    protected $database_username = DB_USER;
    protected $database_password = DB_PASSWORD;
    protected $database_name = DB_NAME;
    protected $database_type = DB_TYPE;

    public function __construct() {

        try {
            parent::__construct($this->database_type . ':host=' . $this->database_hostname . ';dbname=' . $this->database_name, $this->database_username, $this->database_password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}



//--TEST CLASS
class test1 {

    //--INSIDE MY FUNCTIONS I WANT TO BE ABLE TO USE A $db to do my msql stuff
    public function test1a() {

        $stmt = $db::prepare('SELECT * FROM table');
        $stmt->excute();
    }

}

//--TEST CLASS 2
class test2 {

    public function test2a() {

        $stmt = $db::prepare('SELECT * FROM table');
        $stmt->excute();
    }

}

//--CREATE THE DATABASE GLOBAL
 $db = new Database();
 $testers = new test2();
```

If i did the above i would get an error saying that $db is Undefined variable: db

Comment: Have you tried `parent::$db`?

Comment: Thank you for help but parent would not work as im not extending the class

Answer (score 1):

Although I read that was not recommended, you can do the following: outside of all the classes (in the global scope) initialize your connection:
`$db = new Database();`
Then in every function where you need your Db connection, write this:
`global $db;`

Comment: Here is one of many threads on the topic of why globals are generally considered bad practice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357187/when-are-global-variables-acceptable

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `global` keyword on global variables. `$db` is surely one of them.

Comment: Thanks for help, what about making a static var able every where?

Comment: What do you actually mean? If you have to call static methods (`$db::doSomething()`), then no difference. Make a `global $db;` and that'll be it)

Comment: Oh ok cause i have a static class so i could do that ... thanks

Answer (score 1):

When using `$db` inside a function, PHP expects the variable to be in the local function scope. To access the global variable, use either

1. `$GLOBALS['db']->prepare` (**important**: Use `->` instead of `::`; calling `prepare` statically will not work), **or**
2. `global $db; $db->prepare(...);`

Comment: Thank you for help but could a make it a static class and return it as static var... not sure how i could do this..